# Installing JDK on Ubuntu?

Tags: jdk, oracle

I am quite new to Ubuntu. I have recently installed 14.04 on my PC and it's fantastic. My only real issue for Ubuntu is that I need an Internet connection to install things effectively. I had recently downloaded the Oracle JDK (1.8.0_77 for 32 bit) and tried to install it. I know for sure that I am running 32 bit. When I unpacked the `tar.gz` and put it into `/usr/lib/jvm` (I have also tried this in `/usr/local/java`) and I used all the necessary commands (sudo updates alternatives, etc) but when I run `/usr/lib/JVM/jdk1.8.0_77/bin/java` I get an error:

```
bash: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_77/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Is there something I did wrong? Is there a way for me to easily install JDK on my PC without Internet connection?

Answer (score 0):

It's 2016. You should have an internet connection.

If you don't have an internet connection, you can still use packages. Download the package [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/openjdk-7-jre). This is Java 7. There is no official Java 8 package for Ubuntu 14.04, so you'd need the get it from a thirdparty website if you really want Java 8.

You need the one for `i386` because you're running a 32 bit system. Make sure to also download all packages that package depends on and install them before you install the package you intend to install.

You can install a downloaded package via:

```
sudo dpkg -i fileYouDownloaded.deb
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, This doesn't exactly help. I would need to go through and download each required package by hand. A tool like Synaptic would be nice if only for android. ( Also last I checked not everyone in the world has access to internet, maybe some sense of understanding would be nice. Internet is expensive, would you like to pay my bills? )